# Hover one element to change another works but no other way around?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make little effect on my div that says Zobla in it(#zoblaDiv) and for that i need another div (.zoblaEfekat).ZoblaEfekat div is supposed to do something while i hover #zoblaDiv but i am not able to make this work. It only works if i try to do other way around which is not useful to me.They are both in same container.

[image]

[image]

```
.zoblaEfekat:hover + #zoblaDiv {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

#zoblaDiv:hover + .zoblaEfekat {
  border: 1px solid yellow
}
```

Pointer invisible due to use of snipping tool. On picture 1 its on the div on the left(.zoblaEfekat), pic 2 is on the #zoblaDiv. HELP !

Comment: Can you also share your html with us?

Comment: short answer NO, Long answer: There's no selector in css that selects backward/upward in the DOM tree the `+` selector selects the elements that comes immediately after `a + p ` will selects all `<p>` element that are placed after an `<a>`, the `~` selects the elements that preceded `a ~ p` all `<p>` that comes after an `<a>` in the DOM tree

Comment: Thanks man, didn't know about that !